# .htaccess exclude subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following opencart .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteRule ^image-smp/(.*) index.php?route=product/smp_image&name=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm currently replacing the old store which used to be in x-cart. I moved it to:

```
example.com/old/
```

What I'm trying to do is to have this old store still accessible when users go to:

```
 example.com/old/ or example.com/old/admin/
```

(Reason being there's still some old customer orders needing to be processed. )
The main problem is that when I go to those urls, the root .htaccess overrides these and give the opencart 404 page.

Anyone know how to tamper with the htaccess to get both CMS working on the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. This current setup will read html and php pages if they exist, otherwise the rules set in the root htaccess will take effect. The reason I wasn't able to get the files to work was because of permissions, which ended up costing me quite a bit of time tinkering.

For future people who land on this page, make sure you have your directory permissions set to 755 and file permissions set to 644.

For directories:

```
 find /path/to/base/dir -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
```

For Files:

```
find /path/to/base/dir -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
```